# Mid-point between two dates

Tags: javascript, date

What is the most efficient and syntactically elegant way to determine the half way point between two dates in Javascript.

```
var difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
var midpoint = new Date(date1.getTime() + difference / 2);
```

Is this a good approach?

Comment: What else can you do? Apart from caching the `date1.getTime()` variable and/or placing it in a function, what do you want?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That is indeed the most efficient way, with one correction:

```
var midpoint = new Date((date1.getTime() + date2.getTime()) / 2);
```

The mid-point is the average of the two points.